# I can't sign in to microsoft using a public Wi-Fi

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, wifi

I have connected to public Wi-Fi that probably blocks me from some sites. I installed a vpn that enables me access those blocked website but I still can't sign in to Microsoft.

I recently installed a new Windows 10, when I downloaded Visual Studio web Installer, it wasn't installing because it couldn't download the files using the public wifi, while with the same wifi, I downloaded and installed Visual Studio onthe previous Windows 10 that I was using.

I dont know if the problem is from the new Windows 10 or the WiFi's firewall rules have been elavated.

Comment: Hi, when you are using the WIFI, open the default browser and access : https://account.microsoft.com/account?lang=en-us and check if you can login in with your Microsoft account or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing it with open DNS.
For that, open your CMD, type `ipconfig/all`
there, look for your ipv4 address, default gateway and subnet and note it.

Now go to your Control Panel -> Network and Sharing -> Select the network/wifi you're connected to,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l54un.png)

Click on properties, look for the ipv4 checkbox and click on it, then advance.
There you need to select the option to manually enter ip address. Now add that IP address, default gateway, and subnet mask you noted before.

Add DNS manually and set values to : `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Enjoy surfing the net!

Comment: the wifi has connected but no internet

Comment: Hi, to identify router problems, connect other devices like your mobile phone to the WiFi and see if it works. If the Internet works fine on other devices, the problem lies with your device and its WiFi adapter. On the other hand, if the Internet doesn’t work on other devices too, then the problem is most likely with the router or the Internet connection itself.